# F# equivalent of LINQ Single

Tags: linq, f#, seq

Ok, so for most LINQ operations there is a F# equivalent.
(Generally in the Seq module, since Seq= IEnumerable)

I can't find the equiv of `IEmumerable.Single`, I prefer `Single` over `First` (which is Seq.find), because it is more defensive - it asserts for me the state is what I expect.

So I see a couple of solutions (other than than using Seq.find).
(These could be written as extension methods)

The type signature for this function, which I'm calling only, is

```
('a->bool) -> seq<'a> -> 'a

let only =  fun predicate src -> System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<'a>(src, predicate)

let only2 = Seq.filter >> Seq.exactlyOne
```

`only2` is preferred, however it won't compile (any clues on that?).

Comment: As I don't know the question I will stick to this comment: the reason why there is nothing like single in F# might be that you normaly go and try to do your stuff in F# without raising exceptions (for example by using optional)

Comment: find raises exceptions. tryFind returns optional.
trySingle would still have to raise exceptions though (for toomany items) though i guess it could instead return`Some 'a| None| Allof seq<'a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F# 2.0, this is a solution works without enumerating the whole sequence (close to your 2nd approach):

```
module Seq =
    let exactlyOne seq =
        match seq |> Seq.truncate 2 with
        | s when Seq.length s = 1 -> s |> Seq.head |> Some
        | _ -> None

    let single predicate =
        Seq.filter predicate >> exactlyOne
```

I choose to return `option` type since raising exception is quite unusual in F# high-order functions.

**EDIT:**

In F# 3.0, as @Oxinabox mentioned in his comment, [Seq.exactlyOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289759%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists in Seq module.

Comment: BTW: 
Seq.exactlyOne exists in F# 3.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289759%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
let Single source f =
    let worked = ref false
    let newf = fun a -> 
        match f a with
        |true -> 
            if !worked = true then failwith "not single"
            worked := true
            Some(a)
        |false -> None
    let r = source |> Seq.choose newf
    Seq.nth 0 r
```

Very unidiomatic but probably close to optimal

### EDIT:

Solution with `exactlyOne`

```
let only2 f s= (Seq.filter f s) |> exactlyOne
```

Comment: Remember: Seq.filter is delayed operation,
and Seq.exactlyOne, (assumably) throws an exception after 'pulling' 2 elements from the seq returned by Seq.filter.
That means by combing those two functions youcan get a idiomatic and optimal solution

Comment: @Oxinabox - my F# doesn't have `Seq.exactlyOne` - but I added a solution based on it

Comment: as i was suggestin, your new code it much more F# (being that it doens't have mutabiles