# Does F# have Seq.Single: seq<'a> -> 'a?

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F# equivalent of LINQ Single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850769/f-equivalent-of-linq-single)

This function should return the first element of the sequence if it's the only one, otherwise it throws exception.

Does F# have this as built-in function? If not, why is it? Seems C# has a similar one in Enumerable class extension functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Seq.exactlyOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289759%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Thanks! It comes with VS 11. I didn't find this function in previous versions.